# Rails form tag errors out when encountering a binary field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a `binary` column type in my "users" table and when I try to include that field within simple_form_for tag, I get an error.

```
= simple_form_for @user
  = f.input :secret_number
```

Here's the error-

```
No input found for binary
```

Some extra information that might be useful - so I am storing some encrypted information in this column. The data is encrypted at the time ActiveRecord is saved. But in the form that is presented to the user I want to show padded up data, something like - *****456". I have written the following method to decrypt/pad-up secret_number.

```
def secret_number
  decrypt_and_pad_up(self.secret_number)
end
```

Comment: What type of input should this show up as?

Comment: just a normal input box type=text

Comment: Your `secret_number` method, as written, would override `self.secret_number`, and thereby call itself recursively. It should probably be `decrypt_and_pad_up self[:secret_number]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see where the error is being raised in [`SimpleForm::FormBuilder#find_mapping`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L403-419). The reason you're getting this error is because simple_form asks Rails what type of data the given attribute contains--`:binary` in this case (Rails doesn't know or care that you overrode the `secret_number` method)--in order to decide what type of form field to generate. Since there's no way to know what kind of form field a binary attribute should use you get this error.

Naturally, the solution is [in the docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder%3ainput). If you want it to display as a text input, use the `:as` option:

```
f.input :secret_number, :as => :string
```